# Why onTap is not working in my flame game (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, uigesturerecognizer, game-physics, gesture-recognition, flame

I am working on a simple game using Flame and Flutter. I am following this tutorial:
[Create a Mobile Game with Flutter and Flame – Beginner Tutorial](https://jap.alekhin.io/create-mobile-game-flutter-flame-beginner-tutorial)

But after I added some code following tutorial line:

```
flameUtil.addGestureRecognizer(tapper);
```

appears underlined and `onTap` function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

API of `flutter-flame` library is constantly evolving and the solution from tutorial above might not work anymore.

I had some hard times to re-implement example from this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFpjEH-ok2s, so you're not alone :-)

Newer versions of `flutter-flame` like `0.23.0`, requires to make it work to add `TapDetector` mixin to your `BaseGame` class like below:

```
class MyBaseGame extends BaseGame with TapDetector, DoubleTapDetector {
  @override
  void onTapDown(_) {
    add(RenderedTimeComponent(Timer(1)..start()));
  }

  @override
  void onDoubleTap() {
    add(RenderedTimeComponent(Timer(5)..start()));
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/00ad86eb63aa54b411f1d080fec501dd7b671a81/doc/examples/timer/lib/main.dart

Thanks to this your code of BoxGame initialization is just:

```
BoxGame game = BoxGame();
runApp(game.widget);
```

without declarations of `Util` and `TapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TapDetector` mixin:

class WarriorGirlGame extends FlameGame with TapDetector {
@override
void onTapDown(TapDownInfo info) {
...
}
}

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?